# Why is my program returning certain spanish characters in unicode?

Tags: java, maven, unicode

I wrote a very simple maven program that uses the text translator API by DEVISTY and displays it.

[image: HERE IS A SAMPLE OF THE RESULTS OF MY PROGRAM]

The translation is fine on the endpoints on the API website, and the translation is great, but when I display it as a string here, as you can see the upside down question mark and the e with the accent are displayed in Unicode.

Is there a way I can display it with regular characters? I tried to turn it to `utf-8` somewhere but its the same results. Here is the code:

```java
package myprogram.translator;


import java.net.URLEncoder;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        stringGen gen = new stringGen();
        
        // TEST APPLICATION(lets hope it runs)
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String startL;
        String targetL;
        String translateThis;
        String end;
        
        System.out.println("What would you like to be your starting language?");
        startL = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What would you like to be your target language?");
        targetL = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What would you like to translate exactly?");
        translateThis = scan.nextLine();
        
        end = gen.finalInput(startL, targetL, translateThis);
        
        System.out.println(end);
        
        HttpResponse<String> letsgetit = Unirest.post("https://text-translator2.p.rapidapi.com/translate")
                .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "ef0ddf5c2dmsh5ccc18a926d497cp1b6b93jsn9f9e3bdc6353")
                .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "text-translator2.p.rapidapi.com")
                .body(end)
                .asString();
        
       String hutas = letsgetit.getBody();
        
       byte[] bytes = StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(hutas);
       
       String utf8EncodedString = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(bytes);
       
       System.out.println(utf8EncodedString);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Is there a way I can display it with regular characters? ` - what do you mean? ascii?

Comment: Sure ascii, like in idk regular texting I guess. I definetly dont want unicode.

Comment: Have you had a look at an ascii table?  Do you see any any upaside down question marks?

Comment: Why don't you try [escaping](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.8.1/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) the String?

Comment: The answer you receive *is* pure ASCII - because that doesn't contain any "special" (language specific) characters. I think what you actually *want* is UTF-8, so you don't see the `\u0000` encoded characters but their representation in a character of a font that can display it.

Comment: I want my program for example to display autobiografía instead of autobiograf\u00eda (The i with the accent is in unicode). I dont know if its a problem with the way my eclipse console is set up or if I have to change much.

Comment: If those characters are encoded in the JSON response like that, you need to fix it at the source, or maybe you need to set the right `Accept` header in your request, e.g. to `application/json;charset=utf-8`, or use an appropriate library to decode those Unicode escapes.

Comment: Note: write to a file. `System.out` is not reliable on encoding: it depends on the system out (so the terminal), so outside your control. But you have full control the content of a file. So easier to debug.

Comment: I don't know, but maybe you shouldn't give away your API key?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use gson.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Something like that:

```
  JsonObject jsonObject = new 
  JsonParser().parse(hutas).getAsJsonObject();
  System.out.println(jsonObject);
  JsonElement translatedText = jsonObject.get("data").getAsJsonObject().get("translatedText");
  System.out.println(translatedText);
```

Comment: I tried this and it is functioning. Why minus? Can you comment it please? You need to parse it to JsonObject and it is then with accents. And when you have JsonObject, you can go direct to properties of json, what is what you need ...

Comment: It is needed to add to end of your code. It is working with your variable hutas

Answer (score 0):

I *unescaped the string using The Apache Commons Lang `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()` and it works!